# Gradle depends on parallel execution

Tags: gradle, parallel-processing, build.gradle, gradlew

In Gradle, I need to run the tasks in parallel with dependsOn method

```
task testdepends(dependsOn: ['test1', 'test2']) {
    doLast {
        println("Final Task Completed!")
    }
}
```

In the above example I want to run the test1 and test2 in parallel.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

My basic need is - I have to run tasks in parallel. After the completion of the parallel tasks I have to run another task.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle runs inter-project tasks in parallel (wherever possible) if you use `org.gradle.parallel=true` or the `--parallel` flag. For intra-project tasks, you will need to use `@ParallelizableTask` for versions < 4 and [Worker Api](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/) for versions >= 4.

However, be aware that WorkerApi has some [limitations](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/can-we-run-tasks-in-parallel-in-single-build-project/18321/15) and is only useful in certain scenarios.

Comment: I used shell script to achieve this, will try this now. Thank you @Meursault